# compare dates not working

Tags: php

Hallo,

I am comparing 2 dates. It is clear that $db_minus7 is greater so the value of $can_invoiced should be 'maybe' but it is 'Yes'. When i execute.

```
<?php

$db_minus7 = '2010-07-05 09:45:29.420';
$completion_date = '30.07.2009';
if(date("m-d-Y",strtotime($db_minus7)) > date("m-d-Y",strtotime($completion_date))) {
    $can_invoiced = 'maybe';
} else {
    $can_invoiced = 'Yes';
}

echo $can_invoiced;

?>
```

please help

Comment: Thanks for all your answers!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

why don't you just compare the times instad of formating them again like this:

```
if(strtotime($db_minus7) > strtotime($completion_date)) {
    $can_invoiced = 'maybe';
} else {
    $can_invoiced = 'Yes';
}
```

**EDIT:**

if you want to use date(), use `"Ymd"` or `"Y-m-d"` as pattern because it's string-comparision, and this is the logical order to work with (arrange the patterns from "big"(years) to small (days... or maybe seconds, if you need));

Comment: Thanks. I am new to sql, so asking what is wrong if i use, if(date("m-d-Y",strtotime($db_minus7)). converting to a proper date format and then comparing..why it is resulting in yes?

Comment: @user453893 - You're not using SQL here, you're using PHP, and the PHP date() function converst a date to a human-readable string... and you're then comparing the strings, not the dates that they represent.

Comment: Now i understood..i am under the impression date function will return date of format m.d.Y. Now i have checked it...thanks for detailed expalnation. I would have upvoted you if i can..

Answer (score 3):

Dont' use `"m-d-Y"` but `"Y-m-d"`.

`01-01-2010` is lower than `02-01-2009` (**bad !**) but `2010-01-01` is not lower than `2009-01-02` (**good !**).

Answer (score 1):

Compare the dates as datestamps, not as strings:

```
if(strtotime($db_minus7) > strtotime($completion_date)) {
```

If you have to compare the dates as strings, then use Y-m-d rather than m-d-y

Answer (score 0):

Never Compare Dates as strings, even if it works for your Testcases it will fall on your feets sooner or later ... or maybe... richard stallman will hunt you down, i don't know ...

```
if(strtotime($db_minus7) > strtotime($completion_date)) {
    $can_invoiced = 'maybe';
} else {
    $can_invoiced = 'Yes';
}
```