# How to get last record by date but a datatype varchar

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, strtotime

I am trying to fetch data from a table with datatype **varchar**, but I need it to select the last 2 days using where clause by date.

Here I have tried from [this link](https://itsolutionstuff.com/post/how-to-get-last-record-from-mysql-table-in-codeigniterexample.html):

```
$query = $this
    ->db
    ->select('*, COUNT(*) as cnt')
    ->where('STR_TO_DATE(created_at,"%d-%m-%Y") >=', '(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 DAY)')
    ->group_by('client')
    ->order_by('cnt', 'DESC')
    ->get('histprob');
```

But the result is showing all data on my table instead of only two days passed.
My column created_at is shown like: `06-02-2019 23:00`

Comment: so u have date in string

Comment: What is the purpose of the `group_by` ? Also, can you please show sample data, current results and expected results ?

Comment: the proper solution to this would be not to store dates as varchar, that's the root of the problem. There should never be any good reason to do that. the date types exist for a purpose, so use them. Then proper sorting, calculation etc on them is provided by default. Also it would help a lot if you could use the debug tools to output the final SQL generated by this PHP statement, and also provide sample data and expected results, so that we can check whether any of this actually makes any sense at all.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.. I will learn more about using the date dataype instead of converting it to string.

Comment: @devpro Yes, the date is in string.

Comment: @GMB I am using group_by to group the result with the same name (called client).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make a date variable to compare as per your Database column `"created_at"="06-02-2019 23:00"`

```
$compare = date('d-m-Y G:i', strtotime('-2 days'));
```

Then make changes in where clause as below.

```
->where('created_at >=',$compare);
```

Comment: It is working, but failed when compared to different month. For example when fetching data >= 31-01-2019 (31-01-2019 until 02-02-2019) will results nothing. Thanks

Comment: I think this happened because the column created_at is a string, so that it cannot be compared to $compared (datatype date) ?? Then I tried changing the where clause to: `where('STR_TO_DATE(created_at,"%d-%m-%Y") >=', $compare)` but shows all data in the table.

Comment: I have updated the where clause to `where('STR_TO_DATE(created_at,"%d-%m-%Y %H:%i") >=', $compare)` but still shows all data.

Comment: @W. Wan   In my working scenario, I am storing date (datatype DATETIME) in DB in format "2019-02-05 17:04:58" and It is **working perfectly for me for different months** also e.g. $compare = date('Y-m-d G:i:s', strtotime('-20 days')). So for your case, It should be better to change date datatype in DATETIME format instead of varchar.

Answer (score 1):

As per your comment, @Viren answe is not working with different months, so you can also try like that:

```
$currentDate = date('d-m-Y G:i');
$twoDaysOld = date('d-m-Y G:i', strtotime('-2 days'));

->where('created_at >=',$twoDaysOld); // greator equal to old date
->where('created_at <=',$currentDate); // less then and equal to current date
```

Here i am date range between two dates.

Comment: I am storing date (datatype DATETIME) in DB in format "2019-02-05 17:04:58" and It is working perfectly for me for different months also e.g. $compare = date('Y-m-d G:i:s', strtotime('-20 days')).

Comment: @VirenPanchal: then what is the issue?

Comment: as @ADyson suggested in the comment above, In MySQL database we have to use date in DATETIME datatype and  W. Wan is storing date in varchar datatype. So may be that varchar is creating a problem. so it's better to use date in DATETIME format.

Comment: @VirenPanchal: yes, its true

Answer (score 0):

I have solved by converting `created_at` to date then compared it to *$compare* as suggested by **Viren Panchal** but changed the date format from 'd-m-Y' to 'Y-m-d' as *Mark Baker*'s answers in [compare dates not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3804029/compare-dates-not-working) also converted `created_at` by using STR_TO_DATE. Here is my completed code then:

```
$date7 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-7 days'));
$query = $this->db->select('*, COUNT(*) as cnt')->where('STR_TO_DATE(created_at,"%d-%m-%Y") >=', $date7)->group_by('client')->order_by('cnt', 'DESC')->get('histprob');
```

So, comparing date should use Y m d?